# Django - stop synchronisation between different variables based on filters on same object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Sorry about the confused question, not sure how to describe it properly.

Say that I have a model named `News`, a variable `news` will be used to store the filter results of the un-read `News` with the attribute `read=False` and mark these `news` to `read=True`, then return these `news` to template. The problem is that after update `read=True`, the original variable `news` which should store initial un-read `news` will become empty. What's the methods behind this and how to stop this synchronisation?

Code example:

```
class News(models.Model):
    ...
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def foo(self):
    news = News.object.filter(read=False) # get un-read news correctly
    news.update(read=True) # update stored news successfully, but news will become empty

    return news # return empty news instead of original filter result
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). The results aren't evaluated until you actually iterate through the queryset, which in your code presumably happens in the template.

You could convert to a list first:

```
news_to_read = list(news)
news.update(read=True)
return news_to_read
```

but be careful if you're using pagination, you're now evaluating the whole set of unread items rather than just one page worth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and super useful reference, solved my problem perfectly.